# xcode objective c UIImageView animation lagging on startup

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation, uiimageview

Having a really strange issue. I have a UIImageView that moves randomly via NSTimer. The movement runs rather smoothly without any problems, but for some reason right when the view loads the animation will start, then sort of reset and start again making it look laggy and unprofessional. Any idea what might be causing this? I was having this issue earlier, and changing the time interval then changing it back seemed to fix it, but that's not working now. Any help is greatly appreciated as this has really been frustrating me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    fScale = CGPointMake(.99, 1.01);
    df = CGPointMake(1,.5);
    fTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05 target:self selector:@selector(fMove) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
-(void)fMove
{
    form.center = CGPointMake(form.center.x +df.x, form.center.y + df.y);
    if (df.x <.15 && df.x > -.15)
    {
        df.x *= -1/df.x;
        fScale.x = .99;
        if(df.y > 0)
            df.y = .5;
        else
            df.y = -.5;
        fScale.y = 1.01;
    }
    if (df.x < .5 && df.x > -.5)
    {
        fScale.x *= .995;
        fScale.y *= .995;
    }
    if (form.center.x < 100 || form.center.x >220)
        df.x *= -1;
    if (form.center.y <10 || form.center.y >530)
        df.y *= -1;



    df.x *= fScale.x;
    df.y *= fScale.y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.  ViewDidLoad gets called with the view property of your viewController is loaded.  It might be a while (in terms of your app) before the view is added to the view hierarchy and visible, but your starting the timer right away.  Maybe moving the start of the timer to viewDidAppear would make the difference.